# How to use Drools Drl file with WSO2 Business Rule Server

Tags: drools, wso2, wso2-esb

I am new to `WSO2 BRS`. `WSO2 BRS` claims to support Drools. But I couldnt find a way to upload a drools file(.drl extension file). How do I support Drools with `WSO2 BRS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can checkout this entry in my blog:
http://desarrollosoa.blogspot.com/2013/07/wso2-brs-y-wso2-developer-studio-para.html

I hope it help you!!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow documentation at http://docs.wso2.org/display/BRS200/Creating+and+Deploying+the+Rule+Service and use the corresponding version of product mentioned in the doc.